# Interpretation estimates of a gamlss with 2 categorials fixed factors

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, gamlss

I want to know if my response variable "Ratio" is influenced by 2 fixed factors : "Protection" and "essai"
Each experimental units has one level of ESSAI and one level of PROTECTION

I established the following model that best fits my data :
gamlss(formula = Ratio ~ ESSAI + PROTECTION, sigma.formula = ~ESSAI,
nu.formula = ~ESSAI, tau.formula = ~ESSAI + (re(random = ~1 |
BRANCHE_NB)), family = BEINF, data = D_tr, trace = FALSE)

The summary of this model gives these estimates for mu :

Mu Coefficients:

```
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
```

(Intercept)  -0.6092     0.3806  -1.601   0.1140
ESSAI2        0.3542     0.4162   0.851   0.3977
ESSAI3        3.3324     0.3405   9.785 1.13e-14 ***

PROTECTIONG  -0.1449     0.4065  -0.357   0.7225
PROTECTIONR  -0.6274     0.2838  -2.210   0.0304 *
PROTECTIONT   0.1846     0.2982   0.619   0.5380

I understand that mu estimate for PROTECTION R is significantly different from mu estimate for ESSAI1 (the intercept), but what is the sense of comparing groups by levels of 2 different factors ? Indeed,the experimental units belong to one level of ESSAI and also to one level of PROTECTION.

Also, PROTECTION has 4 levels, so why do summary shows estimates for only 3 of them ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intercept is the fitted value of mu
for the first levels of ESSAI and PROTECTION.

PROTECTION-R gives the extra effect on the predictor of mu for R,
which is significantly different from zero (using the approximate Wald test).

Comment: Thanks, If I want the mu parameter value for PROTECTIONR, do I have to add the estimate for level R to the intercept ?